# Repo Partial termination cashflows

Tags: interest-rates, interest, repo

Let's take the example where I buy a Repo with a notional of 10000 EUR and I agree with my counterparty to partially terminate the deal, decreasing the notional to 8000 EUR instead of 10000 EUR. The Repo rate is a fixed one, 10%.

The Repo started on 01/01/2024, will end on 31/12/2024 and the partial termination occurs on 30/06/2024.

What are the cash transfers following this partial termination ?

Many thanks